# регулярное выражение в .htaccess для поддоменов

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, поддомены

**Дано:**

Есть некий сайт, например, `example.com` и некоторые поддомены (`city1.example.com`, `city2.example.com` ... `cityN.example.com` ).

Для основного домена и для всех поддоменов есть набор файлов `robots.txt` и `sitemap.xml`, которые сгенерированы в следующем соответствии url'a и относительного пути к файлу:

```
example.com/robots.txt       -> /files/robots.txt  
city1.example.com/robots.txt -> /files/robots_city1.txt
...
cityN.example.com/robots.txt -> /files/robots_cityN.txt
```

**Задача:**

Написать универсальное правило в `.htaccess` для перенаправления запросов на соответствующие файлы по примеру выше.

В данный момент я использую такое правило:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(m[-\.])?(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(robots|sitemap)\.(txt|xml\.gz)$ $1_%2.$2
RewriteRule ^(robots|sitemap)(_\w+)?\.(txt|xml\.gz)$ - [L]
```

НО! Есть одна небольшая проблема - в нём явно указывается основной домен.

Данное правило предполагается использовать в некоем самописном PHP-движке и не хотелось бы для каждого нового сайта на этом движке явно указывать домен в `.htaccess`, тем более домен у сайта может поменяться в любом момент.

Я плохо соображаю в регулярных выражениях, поэтому прошу помочь, хотя бы натолкнуть на идею, в каком направлении думать?

Comment: поставьте вместо [^/]+ или просто .+

Comment: @splash58, можно немного подробнее, не понимаю о чём вы?

Comment: вмсто example\.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше регулярное выражение заканчивается так, что явно используются имена доменов первого и второго уровня:

```
 \.example\.com$
```

Так как уровни доменов разделяются точками, то достаточно, чтобы регулярное выражение (для доменов первого и второго уровня) соответствовало любой строке с точкой вначале и еще одной точкой где-то посередине (и других точек в строке быть не должно):

```
\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
```

Ежели нужно соответствие всем доменам высших уровней:

```
(\.[^.]+)+$
```

В полном варианте для вашей задачи (только для sub-доменов) будет так:

```
^(m[-\.])?([^.]+)(\.[^.]+)+$
```

Comment: А если вдруг домен будет более сложный? Например: m.cityN.subdomain.example.com. В данном случае основная часть домена это `subdomain.example.com`. Необходимо игнорировать `m.` если он есть, `cityN` использовать в качестве суффикса для получения соответствующего файла `robots.txt`, а всё остальное проигнорировать...

Comment: Дополнил ответ на это счет.

Comment: Тогда другой вопрос: как себя поведёт это правило для домена без поддоменов, т.е. `example.com/robots.txt` ? Будет ли релирект на соответствующий файл `/files/robots.txt`

Comment: Никак... Как вобщем случае скрипт должен "догадаться" сколько доменных уровней вы используете? Без явного указания количества уровней вы эту задачу универсально не решите. Регулярка работает только для sub-доменов. Но если вы знаете изначально количество уровней, то можно решить универсально (указав количество доменов верхних уровней в регулярном выражении)

Comment: В таком случае, если предположить что robots.txt для основного домена (без поддоменов) лежит в корне сайта, то достаточно, чтобы такой запрос example.com/robots.txt не попадал под это регулярное выражение, тогда просто откроется файл по запросу без редиректа.

Comment: вот чтобы запрос example.com/robots.txt не попадал под это регулярное выражение, вам нужно как-то дать ему (регулярному выражению) понять сколько в итоге у вас изначально уровней. иначе как он поймет это домен или сабдомен...